# Change fragment inside bottom sheet

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I have two bottom sheet fragments, authorization and registration. I can open one on top of the other, but it doesn’t look very good. I would like to replace one fragment with another inside one bottom sheet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

So. To implement this idea, I slightly changed the structure of the application. I created a single `BaseBottomSheet` class, in the layout of which there is a container for fragments (I set an empty FrameLayout). Which fragment will appear is determined by the tag in the bungle. Also, if you need to change a fragment to another one inside fragment, for example, by using the button, I created public fragment replacement functions available on `parentFragment as BaseBottomSheet...`

```
fun showAuthFragment() {
    val fragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, AuthView())
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
    expandView()
}

fun showRegistrationFragment() {
    val fragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, RegistrationView())
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
    expandView()
}
```

Also, if your fragments have different sizes, it may happen that your fragment will not be fully visible when displayed. I fixed this by creating the bottomSheetBehavior variable and initializing it in onCreateView *(this is necessary, just calling and setting the value for the BottomSheetBehavior will not work)

```
    private var bottomSheetBehavior: BottomSheetBehavior<View>? = null

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    dialog?.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
        val bottomSheet = (dialog as BottomSheetDialog).findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout?

        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet!!)
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.base_bottom_sheet, container, false)
}

fun expandView() {
    bottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}
```